# grateful to someone for something?

Tags: to-infinitive

I want to express my appreciation to someone who helped me, Can I say: I feel grateful to this person for his help on the project? (I don't want to use thank)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your usage of 'grateful' is grammatically correct - an acceptable usage is

**grateful (to somebody) (for something)**

For example - I am extremely grateful to all the teachers for their help.

Personally I would say "I **am** grateful to...." - for me it seems more natural, but that really comes down to personal choice.

Comment: Yes, the little difference is, I feel grateful vs I am grateful.

Answer (score 1):

> I really appreciate your help on the project.

Or

> I am really grateful to you for your help on the project.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

I'm so grateful (to you) for all your help on the project.

BTW, I'll go for "I really appreciate all the help you gave me on the project"; the use of the appreciate is far more common and idiomatic.